# string to decimal using extension methods

Tags: c#

My string is `1799.00`

I want to like this: `1.799,00`

But i cannot convert this method.

I'm using this function.

```
public static decimal ToDecimal(this object str)
{
    if (str != null)
    {
        try
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(str, new CultureInfo("tr-TR"));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: my input string always same, 100.00 or 1.00 or 799.50

Comment: You are converting your string to decimal. Decimal always has the same representation regardless of culture.

Comment: please inform yourself about a type system and the internal value of a variable in contrast to its display-value/displaying inside the debugger or on the console. to SHOW the value, it must normally be converted to string (implicit or explicit), thats where the resulting format comes from...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are, probably, looking for changing formats. Given a decimal as a string in invariant culture representation (`"1799.00"`) you want a string, but in Turkish cutrure representation: (`"1.799,00"`)

```
  // you want to return string in Turkish culture, right?
  public static string ToTuskishDecimal(this object value) {
    if (null == value)
      return null; // or throw exception, or return "0,00" or return "?"

    try {
      return Convert
       .ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
       .ToString("N", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR")); 
    }
    catch (FormatException) {
      return "0,00"; // or "?"
    } 
  }
```

Test:

```
 decimal d = 1799.00m;
 string s = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

 // 1.799,00
 Console.Write(d.ToTuskishDecimal());
 // 1.799,00
 Console.Write(s.ToTuskishDecimal());
```

In case you want to return `decimal` you have to *format it manually* when printing out:

```
 public static decimal ToDecimal(this object value) {
   if (null == value)
     return 0.00m;

   try {
     return Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
   catch (FormatException) {
     return 0.00m; 
   } 
 }
```

...

```
 // return me a decimal, please
 decimal d = "1799.00".ToDecimal();
 // when printing decimal, use Turkish culture
 Console.Write(d.ToString("N", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR")));
```

you can specify Turkish culture as a default one for the entire thread:

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");
 ...
 // now you don't have to mention Turkish culture
 // ...but still have to specify the format
 Console.Write(d.ToString("N"));
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. but the method return type is string. it's not decimal.

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");

this correct!

Answer (score 1):

I use this to obtain a decimal value:

```
public static decimal toDecimal( string s ) {
    decimal res = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(s.Replace('.', ','), out res);
    return res;
}
```

In case you want to show the decimal value on the format you ask, try this:

```
toDecimal("1700.99").ToString("N2")
```

you will obtain the "1.700,99" string.

Comment: Changet toDecimal a bit, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote another simple example to obtain a decimal value in Turkish format:

```
decimal value = 1700.00m;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR")));
```